# How to retrieve Kazam video/screencast that did not save? Location of cached file?

Tags: 14.04, kazam

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I used Kazam to record a video of my desktop (a Hangouts chat) After I was done, I clicked "finish recording" and I did not get the pop-up asking me to rename and save file. So I hit "quit" , and still did not get the prompt. Now it seems the video is gone. I can't find a Kazam folder on my file desktop, and it's certainly not in video folder, but is it possible that it could be stored in a deep folder somewhere? I haven't shut down my computer yet, hoping it's somewhere temporarily cached, at least. I used Kazam yesterday, for this exact same purpose, and it worked perfectly. Perhaps because the screencast today was over an hour? 
I'm not very familiar with Kazam. I just started using it last week.

EDIT:
It appears after much googling, that there are a number of bug reports concerning this exact behavior( no pop-up window, asking how to save) I still can't find if there is a tmp file location that may have the video sitting somewhere. I'm trying to find if I can resurrect the file, before shutting down my computer, because I'm sure once I reboot, the possibility of saving it will be gone ( if not already)

Comment: I also had this happen to me today. I am hoping you figured it out and can tell me what the solution was.

Comment: @Erin Sorry to say, I never did. I changed my settings to "auto save" from now on. But as far as that video, I lost it for good.

Comment: i found this aout movie.mux files
(perl)
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22279/recover-broken-kazam-video-file-mux

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Download the [perl script](https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer/issues/6)
2. install ffmpeg
3. try sudo for the perl command

VLC can't read the mp4 but youtube can upload and read it

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me when using Kazam, recording a long video, and I was able to find and recover the files. I wrote the step by step in this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/601285/convert-stream-file-mux-to-mp4-gstreamer

Basically, I converted the unfinished temp `.mux` file into `.h264` video file and raw audio file using the [mp4fixer](https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer) utility, and ffmpeg utility to convert into `.mp4` video + audio file.

It doesn't matter if you shut down your computer, the files wont be deleted.

Good luck!